# Cambiar la interfaz del actionSearch, Android

Tags: android, searchview

Hace poco implementé la actionSearch en mi aplicación, de modo que cuando se pulsa sobre el icono se despliega la barra de búsqueda. El caso es que me gustaría ponerla del estilo de aplicaciones como Twitter o Youtube Gaming (os dejo una captura más abajo), es decir, mostrar una barra en lugar del icono de lupa.

No he encontrado información sobre cómo hacerlo, si pudierais ayudarme o proporcionar alguna fuente donde me pueda documentar para hacerlo os lo agradecería.

Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí os dejo el código que he empleado para realizar la actionSearch desde un icono:

Código XML del menú:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Y el código java para implementarlo:

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.videojuegos_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Hola Anto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para que podamos ayudarte has de mostrar tu codigo actual en el que **intentas** poner la barra de busqueda deseada. Has de explicar qué problemas concretos tienes con tu intento, como errores o resultado no esperado. Sigue investigando y para mejorar la pregunta, lee [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado, muchas gracias. No digo nada de errores porque el problema que tengo es que quiero cambiar el aspecto y no encuentro fuentes donde me digan dónde hacerlo.

Comment: En este caso puede ser simple (o no) pero imaginate la situación: *"Hola, necesito hacer una aplicacion igual que la de facebook, pero no digo errores ni nada porque no encuentro donde me digan como hacerlo"*. Este es un caso exagerado en el que coincidirás conmigo que es demasiado amplio lo que pide. Por eso , las preguntas han de mostrar lo intentado y los errores concretos y especificos, para poder centrarnos sobre ello y ayudarte. Has de investigar más y [edit] la pregunta con lo que hayas probado. Cuando tengas 20 de rep podrás entrar en el [chat] donde poder pedir orientación. Un saludo